# Java: What does subtracting a char by a char mean?

Tags: java, arrays

Recently while going through a program I ran into a question.
Below is part of the program

```
public static int numberNeeded(String first, String second) {
        int[] lettercounts = new int[26];
        for(char c : first.toCharArray()){
            lettercounts[c-'a']++;
        }
```

I don't understand what this line of code does:

```
lettercounts[c-'a']++;
```

I guess that it's incrementing the value (which is initially 0) in lettercounts array for the particular character; I'm guessing index of 'a' is 0 and 'z' is 25. But I want to understand how that little piece of code works.

Comment: Do you have eclipse? Have you tried setting a break point and stepping through the code. That would be my approach I guarantee you will get your answer if you did that.

Comment: I believe "c-'a'" converts both characters to their ASCII value and so its just the same as substacting two numbers

Comment: It works as you described it. The code will break if it is fed words with letters outside of 'a'..'z' because there isno index for them in the array. The value of 'a' character is an 8bit unsigned integer mathematically speaking

Comment: Yup I tried using break points that how I guessed it's incrementing the value. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The goal is count the occurrences of each character.

```
c - 'a'
```

is a kind of clever way to get the position of the character in the alphabet. `'a' - 'a'` would give you 0. `'b' - 'a'` would give you 1. `'c' - 'a'` would give you 2, and so on.

That value is used as an index into the array (which as you correctly stated is initialised with zeros) and the count is incremented.

---

It's worth noting that this will break if any character other than `a-z` is present in the string (including uppercase characters), and you'd see an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. And no worries my String value contains only lowercase char.

Comment: Note: Here we are assuming the English alphabet or similar. Obviously, other alphabets would be different. And even English uses other letters.

Answer (score 3):

This basically just converts the character ('a' in your example) to the letter number in the alphabet it represents. 'a' actually has an ASCII(technically utf-16, whose first 255 values are ASCII values) number value (97). So do all other chars. So, if the char is 'b', then the second element of the array (at position 1, 98 - 97 = 1) will be accessed. If the char is 'z', then the 26th element of the array will be acessed (at position 25). You can easily find an ASCII-value table by typing in "ASCII table" in a search engine.

```
int a = 'b' - 'a';
```

Is the same as:

```
int b = 98 - 97;
```

NOTE: You can't do this between lowercase and uppercase letters, since they have completely different ASCII values ('A', for example is 65, whereas 'a' is 97).

Comment: Unicode shares U+0000 to U+007F with ASCII (128 codepoints) and U+0000 to U+00FF (256 codepoints) with ISO 8859-1. All of which is irrelevant. The letters in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block are in two sequences A-Z and a-z so character arithmetic makes just a little sense. Yes, UTF-16 encodes each of those codepoints as one code unit (Java `char`).

Answer (score 2):

`char` variables in Java are numerical values. Therefore, subtracting `'a'` from the value of `c` will give its offset from the beginning of the alphabet. This allows you to use this value as an array index, as you have  correctly guessed.